# facebook messanger icon included in website, want to hide "Login into messanger" popup when we close it. should not appear again during nevigations

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

[image]

I have included facebook messanger on my website..

Its working properly..

when we close "Login into messanger" popup of facebook messanger, then it should not appear during page navigations, after page navigations.. only facebook icon should be there.

My Code snippet:

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
   <script>
       window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
                 FB.init({
                    xfbml            : true,
                    version          : 'v3.2'
                  });
       };

       (function(d, s, id) {
                 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
                  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
                  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
                  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
                  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

       <!-- Your customer chat code -->
       <div class="fb-customerchat"
              attribution=setup_tool
               page_id="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX">
       </div>
```

please suggest me changes to solve this issue

please see the attached screenshot of that popup for information

Comment: You can not modify anything about this other than what the options explained in the documentation allow for. But it should remember when the user minimizes it automatically, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/discovery/customer-chat-plugin#caching

Comment: messanger popup prompting to each and every page again and again, how can i control it

Comment: Check the greeting dialog settings.

Comment: I've added "greeting_dialog_display="hide"".. working fine for desktop and also for mobile.. but when we login to messanger on mobile then it redirect to blank page (url: https://m.facebook.com/plugins/close_popup.php?reload=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fplugins%2Fcustomer_chat.php..).. i dont why getting blank screen on mobile

Comment: if there is fb app in mobile.. at that time its causing blank page issue.. otherwise working fine